# Dropping some hypotheses on a result involving convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables converging in distribution to some absolutely continuous random variable $X$. Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an interval of the form $(-\infty, x]$. Then, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists some $n_0$ such that $|P(X_n\in A) - P(X\in A)|\leq \varepsilon$ for every $n\geq n_0$; this is obvious, since $P(X_n\in A)=F_{X_n}(x)\rightarrow F_X(x)=P(X\in A)$. We can generalize this a bit, letting $A$ be a finite intersection/union of intervals; now $P(X_n\in A)$ can be expressed as a finite sum of terms of the form $F_{X_n}(x_j)$, and since each one of them converges to $F_X(x_j)$ the result follows applying the triangle inequality.

Can our hypotheses be further weakened? For instance, does this hold if $A$ is any Borel set? What if $X$ is not absolutely continuous?

Comment: I think it suffices for $X$ to be continuous on $A$ (or maybe $\overline A$), but I'd like to know if this can be dropped as well.

Comment: I meant $F_X$, not $X$.

Comment: Have you tried showing that the collection of sets where this holds is a sigma algebra?

Comment: @FernandoMartin You started a bounty after I posted my answer. What kind of details are you looking for?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Your answer was really helpful, I was just curious for more/different answers, so I started a bounty. I may have misclicked when I did it since "The current answers do not contain enough detail." isn't what I meant.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Portmanteau states that converges in distribution of $X_n$ to $X$ is equivalent to $\mu(X_n\in A)\to \mu(X\in A)$ for all $A$ such that $\mu(\partial A)=0$, where $\partial A$ is the boundary of $A$.

Here, as $X$ is supposed to be continuous, we can assert that whenever $A$ is such that $\operatorname{Lebesgue}(\partial A)=0$, then $\mu(X_n\in A)\to\mu(X\in A)$.

It may *not* hold when $A$ is an arbitrary Borel set. For example take $X_n=k/n$ with probability $n^{-1}$: it converges in law to an uniform distribution on the unit interval. But if $A$ is the set of the irrational, $\mu(X_n\in A)=0$ whereas $\mu(X\in A)=1$.